# How to remove the topsep of align* environment in proof environment?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, align

Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{align*}
            F(x) & = P(X\le x)\\
                 & = P(g^{-1}(X)\le g^{-1}(x))
        \end{align*}
    \end{proof}

    \begin{proof}
        I want the formular to show on the same line with \textit{proof.}
        \begin{align*}
        F(x) & = P(X\le x)\\
             & = P(g^{-1}(X)\le g^{-1}(x))
        \end{align*}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I want the formular to show on the same line where the words "proof" is in. Hope for your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}\hfil   $\begin{aligned}[t]
            F(x) & = P(X\le x)\\
                 & = P(g^{-1}(X)\le g^{-1}(x))
                         \end{aligned}$

    \vskip-\baselineskip   % needed to align `qed` to bottom equation
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the `ntheorem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begingroup
  \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
  \theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
  \theoremsymbol{\mbox{$\Box$}}
  \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The proof of this theorem is very simple:
\begin{align*}
   1 +  1 & =  2 \\
  10 + 10 & = 20
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this really helps here. What OP wants does not consist of "The  proof of this theorem is very simple:".